# Putting a Google ad conversion tag on a WooCommerce order confirmation page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-ads-api

Has anyone put a Google ad conversion tag on a WooCommerce order confirmation page?

We have our website on Wordpress, use WooCommerce for our ordering and use a Divi Theme.

I tried doing this with one webmaster and we weren't able to get it to work.  We tried putting the tag on the order confirmation page and couldn't get it to work.

Now, I have a new webmaster.  I set up the conversion tag in Google ads and emailed it to her.  She said she used a plug in to set it up on the page.  She said she viewed the page, but I'm still seeing it labeled as inactive in Google ads.

Don't know why we're having such problems?  What's the trick?

I'm not very familiar with Wordpress.  Seems like this should be worked out or other people should also be having this problem.

PHP was suggested as a tag for this question, so I thought I would add it.

Thanks,

Comment: Its hard to answer such questions. Just stating "it doesnt work" does not narrow the problem down at all. Do your clients maybe use an adblocker? Is the script being loaded at all? How do you verify the script is being loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  As I said, I've been working with a webmaster.  I asked them to update this post with the information you requested.

Comment: Looks like I'm not going to get any comments from the webmaster.  The page was tested by the webmaster and I would say she didn't use an adblocker.  How do you test on Wordpress if a script is being loaded?  If you could leave instructions I would be able to test it.  The way that we were seeing that "it doesn't work" is that in Google ads, under "Tracking Status", the conversion action we set up says "Unverified."  It says it can take up to 3 hours after someone visits the page for that to update and it has been much longer.

Comment: *"... I would say she didn't use an adblocker ..."*, if you dont know it for sure you cant count it out. You could invest multiple hours/days trying to do something while this might be the reason. You have to be sure for 100% otherwise everything else might be pointless.

Comment: *"... How do you test on Wordpress if a script is being loaded? ..."* It doesnt matter what framework you use. You can test if its being loaded, if you ... **1st:** Check if the script-tag is available in the html structure. (Then you at least know you told the browser to execute the script, also check if its the content you want to load.) **2nd:** [Check the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for errors, or messages like these: *"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"*

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I will look into this.